# Finding a basis for the vector space in the form of matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Find a basis for the following vector space:

U=Span{$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 5 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 3 & 5 \\ 5 & 8 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$,$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 4 & 6 \\ 6 & 9 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$}

I haven't been able to find any examples of finding a basis with matrices, any help?

Comment: Instead of doing a Basis of a matrix-space, use the 4D vector-space by writing all matrices straight under one another. Then you have a 4D vector, you can easily get a basis from. After that, you just reshape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the third matrix is dependent on the first two. Indeed adding the first two yields the third, hence you can remove the third matrix from the span. Continue in this fashion to reduce to a basis.

You can also consider the matrices as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$.
We can check whether the first two and last two matrices are independent by calculating the determinant of $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&2\\1&2&2&3\\3&5&5&8\\4&6&6&9
\end{pmatrix}$$ Clearly this determinant is zero, hence the four matrices are dependent, thus we can further reduce.

In fact looking at the above matrix it's easy to see that $(3,5,5,8)=2(1,2,2,3)+(1,1,1,2)$. Thus we can remove the vector $(3,5,5,8)$ as well. So now you are left with three vectors. You only have to figure out that these are linearly independent to get the result. You can do this by looking at (sub)determinants of the matrix formed by the three vectors.

Comment: Okay, now I see the 4th matrix of the original 5 is twice the 2ndt matrix plus the 1st. Remove the 4th matrix?

Comment: Jup, just wrote that down as well.

Comment: And I see you found that as well.

Comment: I found that they are linearly independent. Does that mean the basis is the remaining 3 matrices?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means. Be sure to accept an answer if you are happy with it.